# jQuery retrieving text instead of value of select list using two ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a state_city_pincode dropdown. 
In first ajax call it works fine but when i want **c_id** value it returns text.

here is my jQuery/ajax code:

```
$('select[name=s_name]').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url : "{% url 'ajax_city' %}",
            type : "POST",
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                s_id : $('#s_id').val(),
            },

            dataType: 'json',

            success : function(data) {

                console.log("success");

                $('select[name=c_name]').text('');
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    console.log(data)
                    $('select[name=c_name]').append('<option>' + value +'</option>');
                });

            },

            error : function(e) {
                alert('Some error occured');

            }

        });
    });


    $('select[name=c_name]').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url : "{% url 'ajax_pin' %}",
            type : "POST",
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                c_id : $('#c_id option:selected').val(),
            },

            dataType: 'json',

            success : function(data) {

                console.log("success");

                $('select[name=p_name]').text('');
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    console.log(data)
                    $('select[name=p_name]').append('<option>' + value +'</option>');
                });

            },

            error : function(e) {
                alert('Some error occured');

            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: and also how to use more than one ajax call in a page?

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML please? Also, only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want to empty the select list use `$(<selector>).empty()`.
2.If `option` doesn't have `value` then `text` will be returned in Jquery. So while appending use this `.append('<option value="' + value +'">' + text + '</option>');`.
3. Whenever you are updating options from server, emptying the current select list is good, because `append` just appends new options to existing options , which creates duplicate `options`.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great help.

Comment: Yes it is the right way ,  but you can reduce one ajax call by retrieving Cities and PIN Codes in one ajax call. from server send a list of objects that contains cities  in one object and PINcodes in other object.

Comment: If I send a list of objects that contains cities in one object and PINcodes in other object, How I get PINcodes that related to the selected city.

Comment: If PIN codes are dependent on City then you have to make 2 requests

Comment: Yes, It is.     Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is wrong.

```
$('select[name=c_name]').append('<option>' + value +'</option>')
```

You need to add in value

```
$('select[name=c_name]').append('<option value="value">' + text+'</option>')
```

That's why it always return text

http://jsfiddle.net/6nk9c466/1/

Comment: In single ajax call it return value but when I use both first one return value and second one return text.

Comment: Thanks it would be great help.